# django: How to make one form from multiple models containing foreignkeys

Tags: django, forms, models, foreign-keys

I am trying to make a form on one page that uses multiple models. The models reference each other. I am having trouble getting the form to validate because I cant figure out how to get the id of two of the models used in the form into the form to validate it. I used a hidden key in the template but I cant figure out how to make it work in the views

My code is below:

views:

```
def the_view(request, a_id,):

  if request.method == 'POST':

     b_form= BForm(request.POST)
     c_form =CForm(request.POST)
     print "post"
     if b_form.is_valid() and c_form.is_valid():
        print "valid"
        b_form.save()
        c_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproj.pro.views.this_page'))
  else:
     b_form= BForm()
     c_form = CForm()
     b_ide = B.objects.get(pk=request.b_id)
     id_of_a = A.objects.get(pk=a_id)
  return render_to_response('myproj/a/c.html', 
{'b_form':b_form, 
 'c_form':c_form, 
 'id_of_a':id_of_a, 
  'b_id':b_ide     })
```

---

models

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    classe = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name


class B(models.Model):

    aid = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True)
    number =  models.IntegerField(max_length=1000)
    other_number =  models.IntegerField(max_length=1000)


class C(models.Model):
   bid = models.ForeignKey(B, null=False, blank=False)
   field_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   field_value = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
```

---

forms

```
from mappamundi.mappa.models import A, B, C


class BForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = B
     exclude = ('aid',)

class CForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = C
     exclude = ('bid',)
```

---

B has a foreign key reference to A, C has a foreign key reference to B. Since the models are related, I want to have the forms for them on one page, 1 submit button. Since I need to fill out fields for the forms for B and C & I dont want to select the id of B from a drop down list, I need to somehow get the id of the B form into the form so it will validate. I have a hidden field in the template, I just need to figure how to do it in the views

Comment: Can you probably explain a little bit more what exactly you're trying to achieve, what is the intention of having the two forms on page? Do you mean you need to set the ForeignKey fields according to the page the user is viewing?

Answer (score 6):

The code you have is almost right. Just do:

```
if b_form.is_valid() and c_form.is_valid():
    print "valid"
    b = b_form.save()
    c = c_form.save(commit=False)
    c.b = b
    c.save()
```