# How to create single ModelForm for two models that are related by a Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models: `User`(defined by Django) and `UserProfile`. The two are connected by a ForeignKey:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
  age = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
  quantity = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
```

How do I create a `Form/ModelForm` that contains properties for fields from both models? For example, the User Model contains fields such as `first_name`, `last_name`. How would I create a `ModelForm` that addresses first_name, last_name, age, quantity?

Comment: create a modelform for each and display both in the template

Comment: When I press a submit button, will it submit both forms then? To be more specific, in my views.py, I would usually have a line like form = UserForm(request.POST). With your solution, could I have that line + another line (such as UserProfileForm(request.POST)) and would Django then automatically fill in the appropriate fields?

Comment: yes just handle it in the view function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063935/django-how-to-make-one-form-from-multiple-models-containing-foreignkeys) is a rough example

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a model form with

```
class Meta: 
    model=User
```

And add any other Form fields you need like **IntegerField**, **ChoiceField**, **CharField** or other.